# React SSR, Proper way of handling page scroll position

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

My goal is to apply different className depending on the user's scroll position. Well, I need to change the background color of the navbar if the user's scroll position is > 0. I came up with a working solution that works in all cases except the one if the user loads a page and initial scroll position is not 0 (scrolled and then reloaded the page).

What I did is I created a custom hook which looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(
    typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.scrollY : 0,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const setScollPositionCallback = () => setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', setScollPositionCallback);
    }

    return () => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', setScollPositionCallback);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return scrollPosition;
};
```

And then I use this hook in my Navbar component:

```
...
const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();
...

<Navbar
  color={scrollPosition < 1 ? 'transparent' : 'white'}
  ...
/>
```

As I described, everything works well if the user loads the page at the 0 scrollY. When it's not, I get the warning `Warning: Prop className did not match`, which is expected, because scrollY is always 0 on the server side and then scrolling doesn't work, because Navbar keeps ssr class.

What is the proper way of handling it?

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution. The reason why it was happening is, due to this line in the hook:

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(
  typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.scrollY : 0,
);
```

scroll position was equal to 0 all the time on ssr, but when loaded on the client side, it was set to actual `scrollY` at the beginning.

So what I did is I set initial `scrollPosition` to 0 on both client and server side by modifying the line below to:

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
```

and the added one more effect that works on client side only, which sets `scrollPosition`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.scrollY !== 0) {
    setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution when using Next JS! It works. Many of the scroll position hooks out there have this issue and/or don't handle the current scroll position on load.